# Mysql not working

Tags: mysql

I have installed XAMPP installed in my linux machine and phpmyadmin is working fine. But when I tried to start mysql using console using mysql command, I am getting the following error.

> ```
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> ```
>
> '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

The same error is getting when I try to use cake php bake console

** since I have istalled XAMPP , there is no folder named mysql in /var/lib

Can you help me?

Comment: Look at your MySQL configuration (`my.cnf`, probably in `/etc/mysql`) to find out where your socket is located. It might be `/var/run/...`

Comment: This is not a programming question. It should be on SF

Answer (score 1):

Try running your mysql daemon as root.  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start` on ubuntu for example.

Comment: Also try: `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the user that wants to connect to MySQL has the filesystem permission  to open /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock